# NDSolve: multi-dimensional, variable boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations

For a simplified 2D system, consider the case where the boundary condition for a differential equation that lies on a line in the $x,y$ plane: for example, I know the value of $\partial_x f[x,y]$ for all $x,y$ and the value of $f[x,x]$ for any $x$ which is used as my boundary condition (the boundary condition is here given on a 45 degree line in the x-y plane, and not, say at $x=0$). My attempts at using `NDSolve[]` to deal with this is not successful. For example,

```
NDSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == Sin[x], f[a, a] == Cos[a]}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

gives

```
NDSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in f[a,a]==Cos[a] should literally match the independent variables.
```

And writing the boundary condition as `f[x,x]==Cos[x]` gives `NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.`

Another attempt I've tried is using `DirichletCondition`, e.g.

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x <= y && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x <= 1 && y <= 1, {x, y}]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, y], x] == Sin[x], DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == Cos[x], x == y]}, f, {x, y} \[Element] r]
```

but that gives `NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help`. While the result given appears reasonable with this simplified model(red line=boundary condition),

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{x, x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.02]}], 
  Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] r]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I'm worried about the applicability of this for my complex system (e.g. thousands runs with random parameters in the equation, not practical to check each run). I could manually integrate the equation inside a loop, choosing
some appropriate step length, but I want to learn how to employ `NDSolve` directly to get a numerical solution to the equation.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this analytically.

```
pde = D[f[x, y], x] == Sin[x];

Integrate[pde[[1]], x] == Integrate[pde[[2]], x] + g[y]
(*f[x, y] == g[y] - Cos[x]*)
```

Added the arbitrary function `g[y]`.  Now apply your bc

```
% /. {y -> x};

g[x_] = g[x] /. Solve[(% /. f[x, x] -> Cos[x]), g[x]][[1]]
(*2 Cos[x]*)

f[x_, y_] = int[[2]]
(*2 Cos[y] - Cos[x]*)

pde
(*True*)

f[x, x]
(*Cos[x]*)

f[a, a]
(*Cos[a]*)
```

**Update**

`NDSolve` will solve the bc f[a,a]==Cos[a] if you define `a` numerically and:

```
Clear[f]

pde = D[f[x, y], x] == Sin[x]

a = .5;

sol1 = NDSolve[{pde, f[a, y] == Cos[y]}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Flatten;

{(f[a, a] /. sol1), Cos[a]}
(*{0.877583,0.877583}*)
```

Evidently `NDSolve` has trouble if there is no information on y at all as in
`f[x,x] == Cos[x]` and unfortunately `f[a,a]` only matches `f[x,x]` at one point.

Comment: Thanks, but the example above is only for illustrating my questionation and is over-simplified from my real problem where `D[f[x,y],x]` equals to some a random process plus some interpolation function from another set of equations.

Comment: Understood.  Unfortunately NDSolve wants a complete bc rather than a point.  If you change your bc to `f[0,y]==Cos[y]`, NDSolve returns a result, but that may be more information than you know up front.